# Quickbook Enterprise account connect with online

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I can connect Quickbook Enterprise Account  with online by  exporting in Quickbook 14, but in Quickbook 16 we can't, Is there a way that we can export the data from Enterprise and use in the Online?

Comment: Please contact Intuit support. This question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: I have connected Intuit support but no response from they so that i have posted the question in SO